# FluentAssertions ExcludingNestedObjects option does not behave as expected

Tags: fluent-assertions

Consider the following C# code:

```
class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Child Child { get; set; }
}

class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

var p1 = new Parent { Id = 0, Child = new Child { Id = 1 } };
var p2 = new Parent { Id = 0, Child = new Child { Id = 2 } };

p1.Should().BeEquivalentTo(p2);
```

This fails, as expected, with the message

```
Expected property p1.Child.Id to be 2, but found 1.
```

Now we replace the last line with

```
p1.Should().BeEquivalentTo(p2, o => o.ExcludingNestedObjects());
```

but it still fails with the message

```
Expected property p1.Child to be Child
{
    Id = 2
}, but found Child
{
    Id = 1
}
```

Help text for `ExcludingNestedObjects` says `Causes the structural equality check to exclude nested collections and complex types`. `Child` is a complex type, why does it still get checked?

I can make the assertion pass by saying

```
p1.Should().BeEquivalentTo(p2, o => o.Excluding(p => p.Child));
```

but if I have a lot of complex types, I do not want to exclude them all one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I also raised a bug in the `FluentAssertions` repo on Github, and got an answer there. `ExcludingNestedObjects` excludes complex types from STRUCTURAL equality check (as the help text suggests), but does not exclude them from equality check completely. I.e. they will still be compared, but using their default `Equals` implementation rather than comparing their property structure: https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/2210